# I want to disable the optimizations done by clean-css tool

Tags: css, optimization, gruntjs, minify, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am using [**`grunt-contrib-cssmin`**](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin), which is a wrapper over the [**`clean-css`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean-css) plugin.

I have tried every option to disable optimizations done by `clean-css`, I only want `clean-css` to minify my css files, but unfortunately its changing them, for example changing:

```
background:none;
```

to:

```
background:0 0;
```

How I can disable this optimization? [**This GitHub link**](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/150) shows these optimizations are done by `clean-css`.

Comment: It looks like none of the options disable this. I tried them all, even the ie7 compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you tested. No option for `clean-css` will output the css in the way you want, mostly because the plugin objective is create a more performatic and less verbose css, but not necessarily just stripping whitespaces. Which is more of a [development choice](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/150) than a bug.

As you expect both inputs:`background: none` or `background: transparent` will output to the less verbose:

```
background:0 0;
```

Since you seem to only want to concatenate your css, I suggest you [cssshrink](http://cssshrink.com/) which has a grunt wrapper called [grunt-cssshrink](https://github.com/JohnCashmore/grunt-cssshrink)